# Chef-Server Installation can't find chef service

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I am installing chef-server on this VPS that my friend let me borrow.

I was able to install chef and run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` successfully.

I ran into problems because I need to change the iptable rules and I discovered that I cannot find chef-server running on any port or as a service.

When I run `chef-server-ctl` it seems to pass all the tests, so I know its API is working.

Where can I find that chef is running?

I need to change my iptables so that I can use knife to communicate with chef-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off it sounds like you installed Chef Server, not Chef, important distinction :) Second, there is no specific process called `chef-server`. The frontend routing is handled by `nginx` which binds on port 443 and 80 (80 is just a redirector to 443 and can be blocked or disabled if desired). Internally we have a bunch of different smaller services like oc_erchef, bifrost, oc_id, etc. These all listen on localhost and are reached via Nginx.

Comment: sorry, it was a single typo, everything else says chef-server. so if I have to change my iptable rules to be able to connect to it with knife do I make rules for all of them?

Comment: Unless you are firewalling traffic on `localhost` (which would be weird) the only firewall hole you need is tcp/443 (i.e. HTTPS).

Comment: gotcha, ill try that and let you know. (and yeah my friend is paranoid and you need an iptable rule for any single traffic lol)

Answer (score 1):

You have installed Chef server and have reconfigured the server, you can't find a chef-server. 
you can run below commands to check all the services that are running chef server

```
$ chef-server-ctl service-list 

  bookshelf*
  nginx*
  oc_bifrost*
  oc_id*
  opscode-chef-mover*
  opscode-erchef*
  opscode-expander*
  opscode-solr4*
  rabbitmq*
  redis_lb*
  postgresql*
```

To update the port number you need to update

/etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb - in Chef 11
/etcopscode/chef-server.rb - in Chef 12

nginx['non_ssl_port'] = portnumber

And also how are using knife command? Do you want ssl check to be passed then you need to add a line in knife.rb file

ssl_verify_mode: verify_none
'